# UIView animation not working when dismissing keyboard for textfield

Tags: ios, swift

Using `UITextFieldDelegate` I have two function that controls what happens the textfield begins editing and ends.

Using `UIView.animate` I am having a button disappear and hide using the `.isHidden` and `.alpha` property.

`.alpha` is being used because I also animate the button disappearing with a slight delay.

While the disappearing works well, upon using `textFieldDidEndEditing` the animation does not work, the button does come back but it does so abruptly with no ease.

To dismiss the keyboard I allow the user to tap anywhere by using this in `ViewDidLoad()`

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:     
self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))
```

**The delegate functions I use are below:**

```
extension ExampleViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == exampleTextField {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseOut,
                       animations: {self.exampleButton.alpha = 0.0},
                       completion: { _ in self.exampleButton.isHidden = true
        })

    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField == exampleTextField {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {self.exampleButton.alpha = 1.0},
                       completion: { _ in self.exampleButton.isHidden = false
            //Do anything else that depends on this animation ending
            })
        }
    }


}
```

Why is the `.curveEaseIn` not working?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the button is hidden. You fade it back in while it is still hidden and then in the completion handler you unhide the button which already has an alpha of 1. This makes it suddenly appear after 0.2 seconds.

Since you are hiding using an alpha of 0 and showing with an alpha of 1, there is no need to set the `isHidden` property at all in either animation.